# regular expression in python to check if syntax

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am making a basic syntax checker for a language i am trying to make.
The lexical analyzer passes something to the function isIfStmt() to check if its valid like:

```
#IF#RPAREN...#LPAREN#NEWLINE...#VAR#ASSTOP#RPAREN...#LPAREN#NEWLINE...#END#SPACE#IF
```

This is the python code i wrote:

```
def isIfStmt(ifStmt):
    ifObj = re.match(r'\#IF\#LPAREN(.*)\#RPAREN(.*)\#END\#SPACE\#IF', ifStmt)
    print(ifObj)
if not isLogicExp(ifObj.group(1)):
    return False
if not isStmtList(ifObj.group(2)):
    return False
if ifObj==None:
    return False
return True
```

The isLogicExp function checks if the logical expression supplied is correct. and isStmtList checks if the code inside is a valid set of simple statements that might include another if.
The problem is that this regular expression matches the last #LPAREN and I want it to match the one that is for the first left parenthesis in the if stmt line. But it matches the last one in the argument supplied.
`if()
a=(10)`

if i change the regex to`r'\#IF\#LPAREN[^\NEWLINE]\#RPAREN(.*)\#END\#SPACE\#IF'`it doesn't work either.

If I try to use the non-greedy approach with #RPAREN, it has a problem that between the parenthesis, there can be more in the logicalExp inside.
I tries using the non-greedy approach with #NEWLINE as,

```
r'\#IF\#LPAREN(.*)\#RPAREN?(#NEWLINE)(.*)\#END\#SPACE\#IF'
```

But it's not working either. I still match the last #RPAREN